# Array Maps with Dates in Groovy

Tags: arrays, groovy

I'm using Groovy and would like to have a variable that contains an array of maps.
The variable is called "Schedule", it's an array of Maps which contains 2 parameters, Code and Date
`def Schedule = [:]`

Each map contains `["code": xx, "date": yy]` where the code is an integer between 0 and 1000 and date is a DateTime object.

I understand that maps has issues with storing DateTime objects since they are JSON based so what would be most efficient way for me to:

1. Add new map objects to the Schedule array
2. Retrieve map objects by code from the array
3. Delete map objects by code from the array

I know some of this may be pretty basic but I'm stumped with managing arrays of map objects with DateTime within them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might just need a plain old map that is keyed off of the code. Something like this:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

x = [:]

// Add a couple entries

x.put('19', DateTime.now())

x.put('121', DateTime.now().plusDays(4))

// Retrieve an entry

println x.get('19')

// Remove an entry

x.remove('121')

// etc...

println x
```

Comment: This was my initial thought but will the DateTime object be stored correctly? I read a documentation that said avoid using complex objects like DateTime in maps

Comment: Is there a way to pull the entry by date (e.g. I want to pull all entries where the date is before the current time)?

Comment: Did you try to convert it to JSON string and use generated string to parse it to initial map? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that transporting those object using JSON was something that you tried to achieve. If not, sorry for making noise :)

Comment: @rboy

Storage on disk (persistence) seems to be a different concern than the data structures you are asking about. 

Some questions that come up in my head: Are you storing the data in a relational database? Are you using any tools like Hibernate to assist with that? These would be good things to know!

Querying for a range of dates would be best done through a database query, for example, rather than pulling all the data into a map in memory (select * from myTable where theDate > '2015-01-01'). Same with asking for a keyed value (select * from myTable where code = 123).

Comment: using it for SmartThings. It's just persistent data stored in memort

Answer (score 1):

Consider defining your own class called e.g. `Schedule` - it would be type-safe and way better to work with than some unspecified `Map` instance. Secondly, you can use combo `Jackson` + `Joda-Time`. Take a look at the example I put below:

```
@Grab(group='joda-time', module='joda-time', version='2.7')
@Grab(group='com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', module='jackson-datatype-joda', version='2.5.1')

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference

@EqualsAndHashCode
class Schedule {
    final int code
    final DateTime dateTime

    // Just to keep this example simple we satisfy jackson
    // deserializer with default constructor - consider using
    // builder or custom deserializer
    Schedule() {}

    Schedule(int code, DateTime dateTime) {
        this.code = code
        this.dateTime = dateTime
    }
}

// Use Jackson's ObjectMapper with registered Joda date converter
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule())

// Exemplary date
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse('2015-02-10T10:05:03.021+01:00')

Schedule schedule = new Schedule(50, dateTime)

String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(schedule)

Schedule scheduleFromJson = objectMapper.readValue(json, Schedule)

assert schedule == scheduleFromJson


// Let's try it out with array
def schedules = [schedule, new Schedule(100, DateTime.now())]

String jsonArray = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(schedules)

println jsonArray

def schedulesFromJson = objectMapper.readValue(jsonArray, new TypeReference<List<Schedule>>(){})

assert schedules == schedulesFromJson
```

Gist file: https://gist.github.com/wololock/18eedc30426e36a6a995

Using `Jackson` with registered `Joda-Time` type converter you can use objects like `DateTime` in your class to hold specific date. It's recommended to use `Joda-Time` instead of `java.util.Date` for many reasons. It's thread-safe (because of immutability), it's way simpler to use and with `Joda-Time` for example you can easily convert date from one timezone to another etc.

Then all you have to do is just creating your `Schedule` objects, adding them to collection and you can forget about parsing to JSON and reading them from the JSON string.

*PS: If you use JDK 8 you can probably forget about `Joda-Time` and use new `java.time` API http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html I'm not sure how `Jackson` converts those new types, didn't have to use it so far. Maybe you will have to add some additional type converter, you will have to check it.*